# Filter on multiple rows

Tags: c#

when I will filter my datagridview i always had the same problem.
I use this code:

```
view.RowFilter = "Type like '%" + txt_voertuig1.Text + "%'";
view.RowFilter = "Omschrijving like '%" + txt_fout1.Text + "%'";
```

when I only filter on type there is no problem.
After I filter on the type and filter then on the "omschrijving".
In the datagridview there will also show "omschrijvingen" with another type number?

has anyone a solution for me?

Comment: The keyword here is `filter on the type AND filter then on...`

Comment: yes that is what i want to do

Comment: @Steve Too subtle. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Need bold inside code

Comment: @Steve For quoting, use "*this is **quoted** text*". That way you can have formatting. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
view.RowFilter = "Type like '%" + txt_voertuig1.Text + "%' AND Omschrijving like '%" + txt_fout1.Text + "%'";
```

In your previous code, you are assigning a new filter, basically erasing the old one for "voertuigen". That's why these are no longer filtered.

Comment: It works but if I add an empty textbox will that give a problem?

Now i try with my code:

 view.RowFilter = "Type like '%" + txt_voertuig1.Text + "%' AND  Omschrijving like '%" + txt_fout1.Text + "%'" + "%' AND Omschrijving like '%" + txt_fout2.Text + "%'"; 

But this always give an error :the expression contains a invalid string constant

Comment: You should change the second `AND` to an `OR` if you want either one of those values. Adding an empty value will result in the error you report. So you have to check for an empty value, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: But i want to filter on 1 and B ,1 and C, 1 and D ....
2 and B ,2 and C, 2 and D ....

Comment: did you have a solution for it?

Comment: Sorry, missed that comment. Not sure I understand though. What exactly do you want to show?

Comment: I want to show the row where in the collom type match with the input of my textbox type and then filter also on omschrijvingen with the input of the textbox omschrijvingen